# go round by; go by

Tags: vocabulary

> “If you've finished your lessons, Anne, I want you to run over and ask
>   Mrs. Barry if she'll lend me Diana's apron pattern."
>
> "Oh—it's—it's too dark," cried Anne.
>
> "Too dark? Why, it's only twilight. And goodness knows you've gone
>   over often enough after dark."
>
> "I'll go over early in the morning," said Anne eagerly. "I'll get up
>   at sunrise and go over, Marilla."
>
> "What has got into your head now, Anne Shirley? I want that pattern to
>   cut out your new apron this evening. Go at once and be smart too."
>
> "I'll have to **go around by** the road, then," said Anne, taking up her
>   hat reluctantly.
>
> "**Go by** the road and waste half an hour! I'd like to catch you!"
>
> "I can't **go through** the Haunted Wood, Marilla," cried Anne
>   desperately. Marilla stared.
>
> "The Haunted Wood! Are you crazy? What under the canopy is the Haunted
>   Wood?"
>
> "The spruce wood over the brook," said Anne in a whisper.
>
> –– L. M. Montgomery, Anne of Green Gables

Are *go around* and *go by* the same meanings; making a detour contrasting with *go through*? Or is the second *go by* the abbreviated from *go around by*?

Comment: @Jim That looks like the answer to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Go around* means to avoid what's directly ahead by taking a more circular route. In this case it's the woods that being gone around. *Go by the road*, means to get there by taking the road. They emphasize different aspects of the same route- the first emphasizes the "*going around the woods*" the second emphasize the path being taken (and it's length). That is, Anne is scared to go through the woods, while Marilla is not concerned with the woods, per se, just the extra time that going around will take.